# Query string not passed to another page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have two pages default and Regstration.
the default page has below script in the aspx page. Now i want pass the values from default page to Registration page .

JAVA SCRIPT IN DEFAULT.ASPX

```
<script type="text/javascript">

FB.init({ appId:'73055799905339', cookie: true, status: true, xfbml: true });

$(function () {
    FB.login(function (responses) {

        if (responses.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {     // ?fields=events use it and get event detail

                id = response.id;
                fname = response.first_name;
                lastname = response.last_name;
                emailid = response.email;
                addr = response.location['name'];


                                    $.post('Registration.aspx', { id: id, fname: fname, lname: lastname, email: emailid, location: addr }, function (data) {
                                     });

            });
        }
    }, { scope: 'email,read_stream,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_photos,offline_access' });

});
```

REGISTRATION.ASPX.CS

in the page load of the Registration page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblemail.Text = Request.QueryString["emailid"];
   lblfname.Text = Request.QueryString["fname"];
}
```

but still i am not able to fetch the emailid and fname.

Please let me know how to pass the values from defalul to registration page.

Comment: Hello Michael, i dont know if i have to use get or post all i want is send the details from this page to another page. can you give suggetions

Comment: Store this in Session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do a postback using scripts and send these values to server and redirect to desired page.
Here is an example of  [postback](http://madskristensen.net/post/Do-postbacks-with-parameters-in-JavaScript) using javascript.Try it out might solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lblemail.Text = Request["email"]; 
lblfname.Text = Request["fname"];
```

Using generic `Request[]` should cover both `Request.QueryString[]` and `Request.Form[]`. So you're covered for both POST and GET. Also in your call you're passing `email: emailid` - hence read it as `Request["email"]`, not `Request["emailid"]`

Comment: Check if ajax call is actually happening - put a breakpoint at the place were you read the requests

Comment: i want to fetch these values in next page,but it returns null.